# $q.all failing Typescript checker when one item in the input array is not a promise

Tags: javascript, typescript

In Typescript I have something similar to this:

```
    return this.$q.all([
        1,
        2,
        3
    ]);
```

The actual code that I represented with 1,2 and 3 is two promises and one function that returns a number. I also tried two promises and a function that returns a boolean.

Here's the code:

```
    return this.$q.all([
        self.ens.getUserProfile(),
        self.getWordsOrderBy(),
        self.getPos()
    ]);
```

This doesn't pass the Typescript checker and gives a message like this:

> Argument of type '(IPromise | number)[]' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type '{ [id: string]: IPromise; }'.
>   Index signature is missing in type '(IPromise |
>   number)[]'.

Does anyone have any ideas of what might be wrong? From what I understand $q.all will accepts either promises or a value.

Here's the function that I have which is returning a value or boolean:

```
getWordsOrderBy = (): number => {
    this.wordsOrderBy = this.ens.getOrderBy(EnumGetOrderBy.Word)
    return 1;
}

getWordsOrderBy = (): boolean => {
    this.wordsOrderBy = this.ens.getOrderBy(EnumGetOrderBy.Word)
    return true;
}
```

Is there some way that I could make getWordsOrderBy return a promise or some way that I can make $q.all accept a boolean as well as a promise? Note that it's a synchronous function that returns immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [$q documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) `$q.all()` accepts either array or hash of promises. It means that you should wrap values into promises. To do this `$q.when()` can be used. It wraps an object that might be a value or a (3rd party) then-able promise into a $q promise. 
In your case it might look like this:

```
return this.$q.all([
    self.ens.getUserProfile(),
    // wrap value into promise
    $q.when(self.getWordsOrderBy()),
    self.getPos()
]);
```